# how to divide the result of the cursor in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to divide the result of the cursor.
example:
I have 1.000.000 data from the cursor result. then I will divide it into 3 parts.

```
a = part 1
b = part 2
c = part 3
```

and each section will be looped in the thread. I hope you can help me.

**mycode**

```
#my thread
def myThread(data):
     #loop
    for row in data:
        getAPIResponse(row)
        
#get from db
sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable"
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchall()

#divide to 3 parts
part1=???
part2=???
part3=???

#run thread
try:
    _thread.start_new_thread( myThread, (part1) )
    _thread.start_new_thread( myThread, (part2) )
    _thread.start_new_thread( myThread, (part3) )
except:
    print ("Error: unable to start thread")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that after "cursor.fetchall()", all you have is a normal list.

```
third = len(result)//3
part1 = result[0:third]
part2 = result[third:third*2]
part3 = result[third*2:]
```

Comment: Also remember that lists that large will take a lot of memory.  It might be better to look for an alternative to `fetchall`.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Roberts its very helpful.. problem solved!

Comment: @MarkRansom do you have a solution?

Comment: @Arifhidayah unfortunately I do not, or I would have left an answer.  This answer may work perfectly for you depending on your data size, but you should be aware of potential problems.  I assume your data is large or you wouldn't be partitioning it to different threads.